# Format string of text in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, format

I have a string of text that I need to format so it displays properly to the user. Right now, the specific phrase I want to format (a variable) is surrounded by single quotes. That doesn't look pretty. I want to add a `<strong>` tag or `<h4>` tag around the phrase before delivering it to another component which will display it.

Component 1: (Typescript)

```
this.persistingData.changeConfirmationDescription(`Are you sure you want to add the school '${this.schoolName}'?`);
```

Component 2: (HTML)

```
<h2>Confirm Action:</h2>
{{confirmationDescription}}
<button> Cancel </button> <button> Confirm </button>
```

Comment: I got confused with your question especially here - _I want to add a tag or tag_. Could you please add the desired result you actually want and what you are currently getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to insert some HTML into the string then do this:

```
this.persistingData.changeConfirmationDescription(`Are you sure you want to add the school <strong>${this.schoolName}</strong>?`);
```

And then in *.html:

```
<h2>Confirm Action:</h2>
<div [innerHtml]="confirmationDescription"></div>
<button> Cancel </button> <button> Confirm </button>
```

Comment: Nice! That did it!